# SiteOrigin Page Builder remove "Revert to Editor" button

Tags: php, wordpress, siteorigin

is it possible to remove the "Revert to Editor" button on the post edit view via a hook in the used themes functions.php?
I played around with the rendering hook `siteorigin_panels_render` but with no effect :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn’t possible without some custom coding, you will need to change the core files

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. This could be an improvement of plugin imo....